Querying a belongsToMany to the same table using Eloquent
Struggling to get the correct results for a belongsToMany that references the same model.
Relationship definition in the Status model:
public function represents(): BelongsToMany {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'status_represents', 'parent_id', 'child_id');
}

parent_id and child_id both reference the status table id.
Data in the status_represents table:

I want to get all the Status records with a parent_id = 7
Query I tried:
$activeStatus = Status::whereHas('represents', function (Builder $query){
    $query->where('status_represents.parent_id', 7);
})->get();

That returns the status record with id = 7.
Not the status records with parent_id = 7. Expecting records with id: 1,2,3.
In SQL this works:
select * 
from statuses as s
inner join status_represents as sr on sr.child_id = s.id
where sr.parent_id = 7 


Seems obvious now...
It works if I add an inverse relationship to the model. Adding:
public function represented_by(): BelongsToMany{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'job_status_represents', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
}

Note the flipped child_id, parent_id order.
